# How to know if $_POST works php

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['food-input']) && $_POST['food-input']!="") {
    echo "RABOTI !!";
}
```

'food-input' is the name of my Input box with `type="text"` it, but it doesn't print given echo, what can i do to make it work. And other question will code work with `!=""` at the end,i wanna tell to server if'food-input' have something in it and IS NOT EMPTY(second $_POST method) to post the given information. Thanks!!

EDIT:
There is the HTML .

```html
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                             HTML
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="food-input" id="food_search"></p>
<div id="food_search_result"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `if(!empty( $_POST['food-input'])){
echo "RABOTI !!";
}`

Comment: Yap,it is the same,it displays blank page ;/

Comment: Then you'll need to show the form where you get this input from.

Comment: @TsvetomirovYordan Have you tried `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Added HTML form if that is what you needed :)

Comment: Your form inputs actually have to be in a form and that form has to have its action set to post if your looking to access post variables. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

Comment: Show full form starting from the form tag to the end maybe you didn't have the form tag and set the method to post

Comment: Ohh didn't know that guys it displayed error after adding  var_dump($_POST['food-input']); and after reading cteski and smartnet comments and adding <form> it worked <3 thanks to all Thanks for your time <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step by step

try to activate error messages

[How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

and after

```
 var_dump($_POST['food-input']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the HTML you provided, if that's the full code - you're missing the most important tag - the actual `<form>` tag. Simply put it inside a form, using the POST method. After submitting it, you can then use the information submitted in the `$_POST` array.

```
<form method="POST">
    <p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="food-input" id="food_search"></p>
</form>
<div id="food_search_result"></div>
```

Also, instead of doing

```
if (isset($_POST['food-input']) && $_POST['food-input']!="") {
```

you can replace that entire line by the below, which does exactly the same

```
if (!empty($_POST['food-input'])) {
```

## Reference

- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php
- http://php.net/empty

Comment: I am really thankfull to guys like you with exhaustive answers,THANKS mate.I already fixed my problem and marked this question for solved,i voted for you if there is anything other i can do(because i am new in this site) feel free to say me <3 Thanks one more time

Answer (score -1):

You can do,

```
$test = $_POST['name_of_form'];
echo $test;
die ();
```

Regards

Comment: I fixed it with roison and comments of smartnetand and cteski.Thanks for time mate <3